# executeQuery in Grails

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm

I have a little bit of problem with writing SQL queries in Groovy (v2.1.7. Don't even ask, why it's so old :) ). So I, have three tables to join, I can join them on their ids, through a third one, which contains the id pairs. However, I would like to create a left join, so everything, even if it's null on the right side, should go into the joined table - the problem is, whatever I do, the null-containg lines don't show up. I suspect, that it's about the pair-containg table, but I don't know for sure.

```
Table1 {
  id
  sth
}

Table2 {
  id
  ath
}

Table3 {
  t1id
  t2id
}
```

And in its Groovy file, the Table1 has a hasMany relation on Table2.

```
static hasMany = [t2s: Table2]
```

As far as I saw, I have to join through these relations.

My SQL query looks like:

```
Table1.executeQuery(
   "SELECT t1.sth, t2.ath " +
   "FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN t1.t2s t2 " +
   "WHERE t1.sth = ......)
```

Is there any other way to write SQL queries in Grails?

Comment: HQL and Criteria queries support left outer joins. But in order to provide assistance you need to provide the domain classes showing all of the associations (and mappings if you defined them), and the complete query you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Groovy Sql object instead it is amazingly easy:

Just add the def dataSource line under your class definition and Grails will inject your dataSource or if using just Groovy you may need to create a datasource.  Then create a Sql object and use the Object and it will return a hash map of the results.

```
def dataSource

Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def rows = sql.rows("select * from PROJECT where name like 'Gra%'")
```

Here is how to create your own data source:

```
def db = [url:'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB', user:'sa', password:'', driver:'org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
```

Got most of this from the Sql object documentation here:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html

Comment: Can I use it somehow from a .gsp file? I tried to add the dataSource in my <% ... %> Groovy inline script, but it looks like, that it doesn't want to recognize this way this variable.

Comment: Why use a gsp file?  You should be at least doing it from a controller and probably from a service.  You can turn off transactions if you do not need them.

Answer (score 0):

As Emmanuel has pointed out, further information possibly the rest of the query would probably help pin point your issue.

The third table is created by grails and is what is used to keep the relations between what has what many of others..

As it stands now... :

```
def results = Table1.executeQuery(
   "SELECT t1.sth, t2.ath " +
   "FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN t1.t2s t2 ") //+
   //"WHERE t1.sth = ......)

println "-- ${results.size()} "
println "-- ${results}"
```

I would try something like above.. this is me commenting out everything directly after join to get the actual data back.

Then check the results straight after, just in case you are missing a process further down in the code that could potentially be manipulating results further

E2A:

Take a look here and try messing with findAll http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/1.2.1/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/metaclass/FindAllPersistentMethod.html

As it is you can also try other things to see what is going on so:

```
def results = Table1.executeQuery(
   "SELECT new map(t1 as t1)  " +
   "FROM Table1 t1 ")
```

Now with that set 
Look at result this in theory should be everything from table one.. if you now start iterating through t1.. so

```
if (results.t1) { 
 results.t1.each { Table1 entry -> 
     println "--- ${entry?.sth} @@@ ${entry?.t2s?.ath} "
 }
}
```

In a domain class if you have some functionality that returns information outside of the actual domain class variable instance typically you would first build a list of the actual object then iterate through it to query the actual function. Whilst this is not what is actually required in this scenario and what you have should actually just work this is just merely a test to see what is going on..

Comment: I just print the results right after the query, nothing should manipulate the data meanwhile - and I tried , what happens, when I don't use the Where clause - the null containing lines still don't want to show up, still looks like that the Join is not right. Even possible, that these old versions of Grails(1.2.1) and Groovy(2.1.7) are the source of problem, many bugs were corrected over time, but at the moment I can`t upgrade. I forgot to mention, that the query at the moment is in a .gsp file, as an inline groovy script (I mean: <% Groovy code %>), but I think, it should not change anything.

Comment: I just wanted to remove the findAll methods - using them it takes 1,5 minutes to load the page, but with executeQuery it reduces to 10 seconds. At worst case I switch back to findAll methods, the result is fine with it. The "mapping" you sent shows the lost lines as well, and everything looks like fine, still, the joins don't want to work as expected - if you have any other idea, please, share it, but either way, I really appreciate the time you spent on my problem :)

Comment: well if it works the forward way of iterating i.e. as per updated instructions and also takes 10 seconds compared your 1.5 mins then just use that for now. The difference between the later method and earlier join is that in the join you are getting hibernate to do that work. In the later method you have results back and you are iterating through the list using grails mapping. That said keep it simple, i.e. move this monstrous call to your controller that does it in a service and returns results to gsp.. you may different behaviour by simply doing that